# limit with integrated semi-group

Tags: semigroup-of-operators

Let $S(t)_{t\geq 0}$ be an integrated semigroup on a vector space $E$. Let $ 0\leq\alpha< 1$, $ x\in E$.
I haven't been able to calculate this limit, but I expect it to be zero.
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}\dfrac{S(\epsilon)(x)}{\epsilon^{\alpha}} $$
Does this limit exist?

If $\alpha=0$, this case is easy,
$ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}S(\epsilon)(x)=0 $$

but if  $\alpha\neq 0$ what can i do?